# How to rotate and scale cards while swiping

Tags: javascript, html, css

As I'm trying to make a carousel that rotates I wonder how to move the cards rotated and it scales from a minimum of 0.8(left and right cards) and a maximum scale of 1(center card) when the user keeps swiping

```
Scale: 
left = 0.8 
center = 1 
right = 0.8
```

I'm trying to solve on how to rotate them using transform and z-index properties. The cards will also rotate however I'm still trying to make a formula on how to make a function that makes the cards rotate

Any alternative solutions are accepted The animation is
similar to this carousel from codepen however it doesn't swipe [Carousel Rotate](https://codepen.io/pentagonus/pen/gMaJBy)

```js
const CONTAINER_FLEX = document.querySelector('.container-flex');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

let touchStartX = 0;
let touchMoveX = 0;
let count = 0;

let current_translate = 0;
let previous_translate = 0;

CONTAINER_FLEX.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
  touchStartX = event.touches[0].pageX;
});

CONTAINER_FLEX.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
  touchMoveX = event.touches[0].pageX;

  current_translate = previous_translate + (touchMoveX - touchStartX);

  console.log(current_translate);

  items[1].style.transform = `translateX(${current_translate}px)`;
});

CONTAINER_FLEX.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
  current_translate = touchMoveX - touchStartX;
  previous_translate = current_translate;
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #131b24;
}

.main-container {
  padding: 30px 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 900px;
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.container-flex {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 400ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.item h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}


/* ITEMS */

.item-1 {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: #3498db;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item-3 {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container-flex" id="container-flex">
    <div class="item item-1">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/4ue5sgm9/3/

Comment: Try using the  [CSS Flex "order" property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_items.asp)

Comment: It works only if a user clicks the cards however the cards are swipeable tho, though I'm currently trying to solve it with modulo operator

Comment: Not familiar with swipe events, dynamic/inertia scrolling for example; you're saying the code as shown will work for a click event?

Comment: By "Rotate" do you mean the `items` in Left - Right order or each individual `item` "spun" around its center,  in place?

Comment: "Here is a working example" - couldn't get anything to work, apart from displaying three items, on Mac Firefox and Mac Chrome.

Comment: "As I'm trying to make a carousel that rotates " - rotate ... HOW? From left to right, in a circle, going from back to front, flip, turning up side down? Show us with images HOW.

Comment: "when it goes from 0 to 200 however when it's on 205" -- what does this even mean? Is it index, z-index, a coordinate? You need to take a step back, edit the post and describe the whole process, not just jump right into the mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder how to move the cards when it goes from 0 to 200 however

Have all your cards in an array.

```
var cards = [ thing1, thing2, thing3];
```

---

**Use `%` - modulus operator, it's the secret for cycling back to the beginning**

```
      cardIndex = (cardIndex + 1) % cards.length
```

---

---

Copied from [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245430/discussion-between-vince-and-radarbob).  I made it verbose for clarity

```
scrollLeft() {
 nextIndex = items.indexOf(displayed[2])
 
 nextIndex = ++nextIndex % items.length-1
 displayed = items[nextIndex]
 
 nextIndex = ++nextIndex % items.length-1;
 displayed.push( items[nextIndex] );
 
 nextIndex = ++nextIndex % items.length-1;
 displayed.push( items[nextIndex] )
}
```

**P.S.** Write and iterator for items array. An iterator stops after the last item. An iterator is why "for (x in thisArray)" works. BUT write the next() function to return "% this.length-1" instead => now you have a never-ending looper. All that code just above goes away.